# How to get a specific portion of the url using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

```
var url = window.location.href.toString();
```

the above line gives me the url of my current page correctly and my url is:

```
http://localhost/xyzCart/products.php?cat_id=35
```

However, using javascript how can i get only a portion of the url i.e. from the above url i just want

```
products.php?cat_id=35
```

How to accomplish this plz help.I have looked at similar questions in this forum but none were any help for me..

Comment: what parts of the url can we assume are static? will xyzCart always be the page?

Comment: yes, xyzCart would always be static

Comment: I don't think you've googled this enough. You can easily get URL parsing hits on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sliply use this:

```
var url = window.location.href.toString();
var newString = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
```

This will result in: php?cat_id=35
Good luck /Zorken17

Comment: Whay would it crash? If he wants the string after the last dot he can use this logik on any page.

Answer (score 0):

Try the folowing javacript code to get the part you need. It splits up your url by the "/"s and takes the fourth part. This is superior to substr solutions in terms of descriptive clarity.

```
url.split("/")[4]
```

Or if url can contain more "/" path parts, then simply take the last split part.

```
var parts = url.split("/");
console.log( parts[parts.length-1] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the location of the final `/`:

```
var page = url.substr(url.substr(0, (url + "?").indexOf("?")).lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

(This allows for `/` in a query string)

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired result by using javascript split() method.[check this link for further detail](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/x06ywtvo/

```
var urls = [
    "http://localhost/xyzCart/products.php?cat_id=35",
    "http://localhost/xyzCart/products.php",
    "http://www.google.com/xyzCart/products.php?cat_id=37"
];

var target = $('#target');
for(var i=0;i<urls.length;i++){
    var index = urls[i].indexOf("xyzCart");
    var sub = urls[i].substring(index, urls[i].length);
    target.append("<div>" + sub + "</div>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get all necessary values in `window.location` object.
Kindly check on following [CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/rajesh_dixit/pen/EVebJe?test=1) for proper output.

I have added parameter `test=1`
Link: http://codepen.io/rajesh_dixit/pen/EVebJe?test=1

#### Code

```js
(function() {
  var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
  var index = 1;
  document.write("URL: ");
  document.write(window.location.href);
  document.write("<br/> Full Path: ");
  document.write(window.location.pathname);
  document.write("<br/> Last Value:")
  
  // For cases where '/' comes at the end 
  if(!url[url.length - index])
    index++;
  
  document.write(url[url.length-index])
  document.write("<br/> Query Parameter: ");
  document.write(window.location.search.substring(1));
})()
```